# Multiple containers in one ECS cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, amazon-ecr

I have a single Cluster running on ECS. At the moment, I have a single task definition and a single docker container running in the cluster. I would like to deploy a second container to the same cluster that will be running entirely separately. What is the best way to achieve this?

I have tried setting up a second task definition pointing to the second image in ECR, and then setting up a second service for that definition. I'm not sure if this is the best approach.

Are there any good examples online of how to achieve the running of two separate containers in a single ECS cluster?

Comment: You run the second service as you did. Was there any issue with that? Any errors?

Comment: Ah so maybe I'm on the right track. I didn't see any errors, everything seems to be running in ECS.The only concern I have now is the service discovery namespace. When I created the second service, I specified a different service discovery endpoint as I wasn't sure if I could use the same one as the first service. Ideally, I would like to use the same endpoint for both containers. For instance, I'd like to be able to curl the first image at "example.com/first_image" and the second one at "example.com/second_image". Would there be any conflict in using the same namespace?

Comment: also interested in the same question. @northy have you answered your question yet?

Answer (score 1):

> "I have tried setting up a second task definition pointing to the second image in ECR, and then setting up a second service for that definition. I'm not sure if this is the best approach."

Yes this is a correct way to do it, so I don't think you need any examples.

Each service uses a task definition that refers to a container in ECR (or other repo, like Docker Hub, but typically ECR).

Each service could be running any number of tasks (instances of the task definition).

Comment: should I setup another elb and security group for the second image I wanna run? When I try to apply the same configuration to the second instance, my load balancer seems to be routing all the traffic to the first one, so trying to access an endpoint from my second sever results at 404 request to the first one. What should I do?

Comment: No you can use the same Application Load Balancer. You can have the services in the same SG as well, or in separate that both accepts traffic from the ALB.
You then need to configure more than one listener on the ALB and route traffic to the respective service depending on the url/header/path that the client is requesting.

Sounds like you have not configured the listener at all and it defaults to the first service only.

Comment: @ northy  What the final solution as I have a similar situation --

Comment: @Judi if you just set it up like I wrote you should be good to go.